# javascript form submit function doesn't submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

Here is the form:

```
<form name="loginForm" id="loginForm" method="post">
    <!-- <label>UserName :</label> -->
    <input id="name" name="username" placeholder="username" type="text"  autofocus>
    <!-- <label>Password :</label> -->
    <!-- <input id="password" name="password" placeholder="**********" type="password"> -->
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Login ">
</form>
```

And the script:

```
document.getElementById("name").addEventListener("keypress", submitForm);
function submitForm() { 
    // document.getElementById("loginForm").submit();
    document.forms.loginForm.submit();
    // alert("Yay, You got this far!");
}
```

The function submitForm gets called, however the form doesn't get submitted unless return/enter is pressed.  I've tried renaming the submit input, which then again accepts the input, seems to make the function call, however instead of submitting the form, it simply refreshes the form and clears the input text field.

Comment: Your `form` element look like missing an `action` attribute, isn't it ? :)

Comment: Side note: you don't need `document.forms.` before `loginForm.submit()`

Comment: I'm a bit confused with what you're trying to do here. It looks like each time the user types any character in the name field the form is submitted - even if they've not finished typing. Have I got that right? If not, could you help me understand how you want the form to behave please?

Answer (score 0):

It would probably better work with an action attribute.
By the way you should close your empty elements with `/>`

```
<form name="loginForm" id="loginForm" method="post" action="http://localhost:80/my_awesome_form_handler.php">
    <input id="name" name="username" placeholder="username" type="text"/>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Login "/>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need an event listener for this.  This should work for you:

Your form tag must have an **action** attribute.  Point it to whatever script is processing your form.

```
<form name="loginForm" id="loginForm" method="post" action="script.php">
<!-- <label>UserName :</label> -->
<input id="name" name="username" placeholder="username" type="text"  autofocus>
<!-- <label>Password :</label> -->
<!-- <input id="password" name="password" placeholder="**********" type="password"> -->
<input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Login ">
</form>
```

For the javascript, using jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#loginForm').on('submit', null, function() {
        $(this).submit();
    });
}
```

If you're actually trying to submit the form everytime a character is entered in the name field, then you can do:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#name').on('keyup', null, function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#loginForm').submit();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, yes I just realized that I need to set a timer in order to accept all the scanned characters of the badge versus after each character entry . . .